# Выборка и count из нескольких строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть очень большая таблица со следующими полями:

1. id
2. price
3. timestamp

Есть определенный интервал, допустим, 15 минут, нужно обойти всю таблицу, найти все пары значений, между которыми временной интервал составляет 15 минут, для всех этих пар найти разницу **price** в процентах, а затем выполнить сравнение с заранее известым числом и вывести count всех значений, которые больше этого заранее известного числа.

Как это можно эффективно реализовать в MySQL?

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы версию MySQL сказали...

Comment: *найти все пары значений, между которыми временной интервал составляет 15 минут* Строго 15 минут, или плюс-минус секунды? это обязательно соседние при сортировке по времени записи или нет? А дубликаты по времени в таблице есть? В любом разе на очень большой таблице такая хрень будет столь же очень небыстро.

Comment: Версия в общем-то не принципиальна, допустим восьмерка. +/- несколько секунд в интервале - допустимо, дубликаты по времени отсутствуют. Нет, как правило - не соседние, между ними будут ещё значения (средний интервал между записями - минута).

Comment: *Версия в общем-то не принципиальна* Для решения - обычно весьма принципиально. Впрочем, с учётом, что *как правило - не соседние* - действительно, уже пофиг. *+/- несколько секунд в интервале - допустимо* Сколько именно в плюс и сколько в минус? *для всех этих пар найти разницу price в процентах* Процент - от какого из двух значений?

Comment: Ну про версию суть в том, что если на какой-то из них есть более эффективное решение, то не проблема ее использовать. По отклонению от стандартного интервала - до 5 секунд в любую сторону. Считать от более свежей записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 
    ON t1.`timestamp` BETWEEN t2.`timestamp` + INTERVAL 15 * 60 - 5 SECOND
                          AND t2.`timestamp` + INTERVAL 15 * 60 + 5 SECOND
WHERE (1 - t1.price / t2.price) > @difference_limit
```

Особо на эффективность не рассчитывайте - задача такая. Да и результат, без хотя бы общего числа найденных пар для сравнения - практически ниачём.